# What is the name for the mixed ingredients in a bowl?

Tags: word-choice

I am writing a recipe in Japanese. The excerpt is given as follows.

> まず、丼に卵と塩とこしょうと薄切りの玉ねぎを入れて、混ぜる。
>
> フライパンに油を入れて、火をつけて、１っ分ぐらい持つ。
>
> フライパンに「the contents of the bowl」を入れて、５分ぐらい炒める。

The contents of the bowl is the mixed ingredients.
What is the correct pronoun to replace "the contents of the bowl"?
Is there a single word for it?

Comment: +1 but ボウル ＞ 丼.  丼 is used for serving food, not preparing.   Even if some people will actually use a 丼 to cook this, we still would not expect the word to appear in the recipe.  I will not mention the untidy use of three と's in the first sentence.  「と」 is way overrated in Japanese-as-a-foreign-language.

Comment: One correction: 持{も}つ→待{ま}つ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

混ぜた材料を - To be explicit about what you are referring to

And just regarding the rest of your sentence - 
丼 → ボール and
１分 (don't need the っ)

Comment: btw. especially in recipes 混ぜ合わせた材料 is used far more often than 混ぜた材料.